# How is score calculated in Dungeons of Dredmor?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

When you die in Dungeons of Dredmor and permadeath is enabled the game gives you a score. Any ideas how the score is calculated?

Comment: With a calculator? ;)

Comment: You can also see your score by hovering over your character's face on the bottom bar

Answer (score 0):

I think it's based entirely on monsters killed and experience earned. I don't know if they've reset it, but when the game first came out you could actually load up the files with monster stats in them and change the score value of the monsters. This is how people were posting scores of like 4 billion... they'd just change the value of a blobby, kill it, then die to have Steam record the score. So I know for sure kills play a major role.

I can't remember whether or not simply earning earning experience outside of kills (such as through the Archaeology skills) raised score, but if they did, it was a very insignificant percentage.

Comment: At one point I was messing around with the game using a memory editor, and the value for the score was the total experience earned. All XP counted equally. If you had earned 23,579 XP over the course of that game, your score would be 23,579. This might have changed with newer versions.